# Apps closing without apparent reason

Tags: 17.10, filesystem, system

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 on a laptop with 3.7GB RAM, Intel Core i3 4000M CPU 2.40Ghz x 4, 64-bit. I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and I've been enjoying it so far. Frequently, I'm facing a bug that closes all windows I'm working on. I can't open anything and to shut down the system, I have to hold the power button to kill the machine. The image attached is what I see when this happens.

[image]

I found a similar problem in this old thread and I'm afraid to try the same thing and make matters worse. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2048100

Comment: The screen shot shows a lot of hardware issues: Look up how to run a SMART Test on your hard drive.  Back up all data immediately to another media (if not backed up already).

Comment: Thaknyou for the answer. I run the long smart test and it said it passed.=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED you have any iea what else can I do? Thank you.